# Why doesn't the Value get replaced in the variable?

Tags: python

```
A='A'
B='B'
C='C'
D='D'
E='E'
F='F'
G='G'
H='H'
I='I'
list1=[A,B,C]
list2=[D,E,F]
list3=[G,H,I]

def Output():
    print(list1)
    print(list2)
    print(list3)

Output()

print('The object of Tic Tac Toe is to get three in a row. You play on a three by three game board. The first player is known as X and the second is O. Players alternate placing Xs and Os on the game board until either oppent has three in a row or all nine squares are filled. X always goes first, and in the event that no one has three in a row, the stalemate is called a cat game.')
print()
print('This is a two player game. Single-player Coming soon!')
print()
print('You must place your letter by choosing a letter from above to decide the co-ordinates. The first player starts with X, and the second player starts with O.')

Decision=input('Enter Co-ordinate of First player:')
if Decision == A:
    A ='X'
if Decision == B:
    B = 'X'
if Decision == C:
    C ='X'
if Decision == D:
    D ='X'
if Decision == E:
    E ='X'
if Decision == F:
    F ='X'
if Decision == G:
    G ='X'
if Decision == H:
    H ='X'
if Decision == I:
    I ='X'
Output()
```

This was a code I started writing for Tic Tac Toe. Whenever I enter the Co-ordinate and then use the Output Function, the letter X doesn't appear in the place of the co-ordinate entered.

Comment: You probably meant to assign X to the coordinate, e.g., `A ='X'`, not `A =='X'`.

Comment: Vivek, I see you edited the question to fix the bug mentioned by @Reti43.  Did that fix your problem /answer your question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`A` is a reference to `'A'`, Not `list1[0]`. Just because you initialized `list1` with the first value as `A` does not mean changes in the variable `A` will affect the value in the list. Also, you use `==` for a variable assignment. `==` is an equality checker. Here's what you should do instead:

```
if decision == 'A':
    list1[0] = 'X'
```

this way the value in the list will be changed, and you don't need any of the variable assignments such as `A = 'A'`, `B = 'B'`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Because when you do :

```
if Decision == A:
    A ='X'
```

Yes you are changing the value but where are you storing changed stuff ??

For that, you have to tell the list to change at that index and for that:

```
if Decision == A:
    list1[index_no] = 'value'
```

so :

```
if Decision == A:
        list1[0] = 'X'
```